# What is this infinite summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

We encountered an function defined by the infinite summation as shown below:

$$F(x,a):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{-n}(2a-n)x^{n-1}\Gamma(2a+1)}{a(2a-1)\Gamma(2a+1-n)}$$

Where
$$a(2a-1)\Gamma(2a+1-n)\not=0$$

Is there a closed form expression for it?

For background info please refer to [this new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782186/interesting-behavior-of-the-expansion-of-1f-2-alpha-23-2-alpha-21y2-4).

Comment: if a is an integer then we facing $\Gamma(-n)=\infty$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple says it's a hypergeometric function:
$$ {\mbox{$_2$F$_0$}(1,-2\,a+2;\,\ ;\,x/2)}$$
However, this series should diverge for all $x \ne 0$.

Comment: Nice result!  Mathematica 9.0 can not work it out!  We are interested in the case where $x<<1$ and $a$ is a complex number. So there is a chance that this series should converge. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, there is no chance of convergence.  The ratio of $n+1$'th to $n$'th term is $(n+1-2a) x/2$, whose absolute value goes to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ as long as $x \ne 0$.  Of course if $a$ is a positive integer or half-integer, there are only finitely many nonzero terms, but otherwise it diverges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description! $x=(m \pi)^{-1}$ in my case where $m$ is another large integer that eventually goes to infinity. I just need to make sure that $m$ goes to infinity before $n$ does.  Best